# Which scripture does James 4:5 allude to?

Tags: james

English Standard Version James 4:5

> Or do you suppose it is to no purpose that the Scripture says, “He yearns jealously over the spirit that he has made to dwell in us”?

Where is this Scriptural reference?

Comment: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/what-scripture-is-james-45-referring-to

Answer (score 0):

Possibly [Isaiah 26:9] "With My soul, I desired You in the night even if my spirit is within me" (נַפְשִׁ֚י אִוִּיתִ֙ךָ֙ בַּלַּ֔יְלָה אַף־רוּחִ֥י בְקִרְבִּ֖י ).